# layout visibility animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, layout-animation, android-transitions

How do I show the layout with transition duration 2.5 by displaying top of the layout first followed by the bottom not all at the same time .I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

summary:
layout visibility animation with transition duration 2.5 and displays top to bottom not the entire layout at once like javascript-css transition

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    Button b2;

    LinearLayout l1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);


        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            }
        });



    }
}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button04"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button06"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button07"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button05"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to the root view in your layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

This will automatically animate anything you change in the layout! So if you change the visibility of views it will automatically play a fade in/out animation, if you change the position of the view a translation animation will be played etc.

Comment: how can i control the duration to 2.5 secs also fade in from top to bottom ?

Comment: Fade from top to bottom would be very difficult to implement. Of the top of my head I don't know of a simple way to achieve this, even with a completely custom animation. To control the duration of the animation you are going to have to animate everything manually. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-linearlayout-with-a-slide-up-down-animation/19766034#19766034) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614156/android-library-to-create-easily-cool-animations/22614257#22614257) both explain how you can create, tweak and play animations.

Comment: can you change to code above to make it work.It would be of great help.Thanks.What do I need to add to the code above?

Comment: To make what work? If you want to know how to animate manually than see the links I posted above.

Comment: I used `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
</set>`   how do I use two anim both accelerate and fade-in ?